# camunda admin not responding

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-plugin, camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin

I have spring boot project on intelliji, with embedded camunda, and the following version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-external-task-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

when I open the admin tool using the url

```
http://localhost:8080/my-project/app/admin/engine/#/setup
```

it keeps loading and I have the following excpetion in the log

```
WARNING: org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.RestException: It was not able to load the following file 'app/plugin.css'.
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.plugin.resource.AbstractAppPluginRootResource.getAsset(AbstractAppPluginRootResource.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

although when I tried from my friends machine, it opened without any issues !

any idea

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the configration that I used to start the project, as I was using JAR Manifest, instead of classpath file

[image]